# Why doesn't Heroku like strftime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, strftime

It seems Heroku/PostgreSQL doesn't support `strftime`. So, if I want to convert something like:

```
@event.date_start.strftime("%B #{@event.date_start.day.ordinalize}")
```

What are the options without using `strftime`?

---

Edit:

Here's my Heroku error log. It's stumbling on `strftime`, which was working fine in SQLite in my dev environment:

```
2013-05-19T15:51:07.001968+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: what you have and how the output looks like,as you want. Give examples.

Comment: I don't think it's `Heroku` or `postgres`, the same code works for me in the Heroku command line when I try it.

Comment: You are sure `@event.date_time.respond_to? :strftime` and `@event.date_start.respond_to? :day` (meaning: you did not override your attribute getter)?

Comment: I've added the heroku log error into my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `@event` doesn't have a `date_start`:

```
2013-05-19T15:51:07.001968+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass)
```

The above error means that `strftime` is being called on a `nil` object, which in your case is `@event`'s `date_start`.

If your event records should always have a `date_start` then update or delete the problematic one.
Otherwise you can use [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

```
@event.date_start.try(:strftime, "%B #{@event.date_start.day.ordinalize}")
```

Comment: Hmm, OK. Yet I can't work out why strftime is being set fine before I push to Heroku (and it's fine if I run the same code in Ruby console).

Comment: This is to do with the records saved in your database. So on your development database your records are fine, but on Heroku one or more of your event records doesn't have that field saved correctly. Run `heroku run rails console` and `Event.where("date_start is null")` to find the bad records.

Comment: Thanks mind.blank – I had one record (the first one) without data and it was throwing the rest off!